# Make Perl script work in both Perl 5 and 6

Tags: forms, perl, portability, raku

I have a Perl script that needs to run on both Perl 5 and Perl 6 environments.  If using Perl6 I need to use "perl6::Form" while on Perl5 I need to use "Format".

This code works on both versions or perl without error:

```
BEGIN {
    if( $] ge 6){
        require Perl6::Form;
        Perl6::Form::->import();
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to "separate" the Perl6 code when running on Perl5.

```
if( $] ge 6){ # Perl6
    print form
    ...
    ...
} else { # perl5
    format STDOUT =
    ...
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work cleanly as I get errors on Perl5:

```
Unquoted string "form" may clash with future reserved word at /usr/bin/script.pl line 628.
Name "main::form" used only once: possible typo at /usr/bin/script.pl line 641.
```

I've briefly looked at `Text::CPP`, but I don't want to have a dependency on a compiler being installed.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I sense some confusion ... [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ Perl6::Form) is a Perl5 module ... I have basically ignored Perl6 so far ... so I am probably missing something ... Where did you get the idea that you could combine Perl5 and Perl6 code in the same source like that? I am curious.

Comment: Perl6::form is not available on my RHEL 6.4 system running perl v5.10.1.

Comment: The issue I'm running into in that using perl6 complains when I use "format STDOUT=".  So on these systems I have to use perl6::Form, but if perl6::Form is not available I have to use "format"

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that `Perl6::Form` is a CPAN module for Perl5.

Comment: AFAIK, Perl5 and Perl6 are rather different languages. Could you please tell me where you got the idea that you can combine both of them in the same source file?

Comment: Well I come from a C background, and we use preprocessor commands to make our code portable on many platforms.  I was hoping I could do that with perl.  Sounds like that's not possible.

Comment: ok, C background example: When's the last time you mixed C and Java in the same source file?

Comment: Ok fair enough.  I look into other options.  I was just "hoping" I could do this.

Comment: Hoping to do what? There are many ways of putting two files into one. It's just not useful to do so here.

Comment: perl5 has a command line switch that runs the input through the C preprocessor; dunno if perl6 does, but if so, that could do it.  but Sinan Ünür is correct: perl5 and perl6 are *different languages*, not just different versions, so your problem here is not likely to be shared by many and the available solutions will reflect that.

Comment: All I was trying to do, was if a module is available then use code/subroutines from that module, if not, then use this other code.

Comment: If that was all, why were you mentioning different versions of Perl at all?

Comment: because I incorrectly thought "perl6::Form" only came with perl6

Comment: Again, there's no such thing as perl6::Form

Comment: "Unsupported use of $] variable; in Perl 6 please use $*PERL_VERSION
at tmp.pl:1" using  2013.08-15-g789db4f

Answer (score 12):

> If using Perl6 I need to use "perl6::Form"

perl6::Form doesn't exist.

[Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl6::Form) is a Perl5 module that provides functionality similar to Perl6's `form`.

A Perl6 module would have no use for Perl6::Form even it could run it since it's part of the language.

> But I do not know how to "separate" the Perl6 code when running on Perl5.

Perl6 is not a version of Perl5. Perl5 and Perl6 are completely different languages. (Perl5's latest version is currently 18.1) I don't see how you can think you can have a program executed by both.

The best way to separate a Perl5 program and a Perl6 program is to put them in different files. If you have a need to place them in the same file, you'll need to state that need for us to help you find an appropriate solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say they're *completely* different languages, but they're certainly different enough that mixing them in one source file is not likely to be worth the effort. I seem to recall that Perl6 originally had a design goal of being able to execute Perl5 code [citation needed], but I don't think that's been done, and I wouldn't count on it ever actually happening.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Java's syntax is about as similar to C's as Perl6's is to Perl5's. I call that completely different languages.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, The idea was to create an *interpreter* that could run Perl5 and Perl6 (i.e. Parrot). Perl6 wouldn't run Perl5 since Perl6 is not a program.

Comment: I call C and Klingon *completely* different languages, but I think we're agreed that they're different enough that writing code that's valid Perl5 and valid Perl6 would be a mere stunt rather than anything useful.

Comment: using Perl5 modules from Perl6 and freely intermixing both at block level is supposed to work (someday); you actually can patch some limited Perl5 support into Rakudo via https://github.com/rakudo-p5/v5 right now

Comment: @ikegami They are not *totally* different. Perl5 to Perl6 is more like C to C++. In final implementation it will be posible to use mix them perl6.

Comment: @teodozjan, You can just as easily mix FORTRAN and C, but that doesn't make them the same language.

Comment: @teodozjan, And you're wrong as to be being like C and C++. C is mostly a subset of C++, but Perl5 is not a subset of Perl6. You can't pretend that Perl5 code is Perl6 code like you can pretend C code is C++ code, and that was the whole point. You cannot have a piece of code be valid Perl5 and Perl6 code. Please reread the OP and refrain from further emotionally motivated, off-topic replies.

Comment: It would be a pretty neat stunt to have code that can execute in either environment.  Or maybe it just needs a controlling shell script that can call one or the other... or maybe they just need to both have interpreters for a common auxiliary DSL... or...